# How to add static JSON files to Webpack output/dist directory?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to add some static JSON files into webpack output directly for referring at run time.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy the assets to the dist.

Comment: yayayayayya! Gettin paid!